# Show background process status in JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

Is there any way to write text in `JTextArea` about background process. I have one button on screen. When user click on that button, some process is started. I want to show ongoing status of that process on screen which is in Text area. After doing `textArea.append("Some status")` I use to call `textArea.repaint()` but this not work for me.

Should I need to implement my own Thread for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply can use a [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html), where you really doesn't have to worry about performing the periodic task on the `Event Dispatcher Thread`. You simply will call `publish()` inside `doInBackground()` method to append the specified text to `JTextArea`, which will invoke `process()` and perform the whole task on `Event Dispatcher Thread` automatically.

Have a look at this working example :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class LoadingImage {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextArea logArea;
    private JLabel imageLabel;
    private ImageIcon[] images;
    private JButton startStopButton;
    private String[] path;
    private int counter;

    private Timer timer;

    private ActionListener timerAction = 
                            new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            counter %= path.length;
            imageLabel.setIcon(images[counter++]);
        }
    };

    private ActionListener buttonAction = 
                            new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            if (timer.isRunning()) {
                startStopButton.setText("Start");
                timer.stop();
            }
            else {
                startStopButton.setText("Stop");
                timer.start();
            }
        }
    };

    public LoadingImage() {
        imageLabel = new JLabel("Nothing to display yet...", JLabel.CENTER);
        images = new ImageIcon[5];
        path = new String[] {
            "http://i.imgur.com/922oehL.gif",
            "http://i.imgur.com/2Fim5t4.gif",
            "http://i.imgur.com/jJKlCiI.gif",
            "http://i.imgur.com/0KuZuGl.gif",
            "http://i.imgur.com/evuKoI5.gif"
        };
        counter = 0;
    }

    private void displayGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Loading Image Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2, 5, 5));
        logArea = new JTextArea(10, 10);
        JScrollPane logScroller = new JScrollPane();
        logScroller.setViewportView(logArea);

        centerPanel.add(logScroller);
        centerPanel.add(imageLabel);
        contentPane.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        startStopButton = new JButton("Stop");
        startStopButton.addActionListener(buttonAction);
        contentPane.add(startStopButton, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        new BackgroundTask().execute();
        timer = new Timer(1000, timerAction);
        timer.start();
    }

    private class BackgroundTask extends SwingWorker<ImageIcon[], String> {
        @Override
        protected ImageIcon[] doInBackground() {
            ImageIcon[] images = new ImageIcon[path.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < path.length; i++)
            {
                try {
                images[i] = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new URL(path[i])));
                }catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
                publish(String.format("Loaded : %s%n", path[i]));
            }

            return images;
        }

        @Override
        protected void process(java.util.List<String> messages) {
            for (String message : messages)
                logArea.append(message);
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            try {
                images = get();             
            } catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new LoadingImage().displayGUI();
            }
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater(runnable);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `textArea.repaint()` call is completely superfluous. After a call to `append`, `repaint` is automatically called, so you don't need to call it.

Here's an example:

```
Process p = ...; // start the process somehow
final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
new Thread() {
    private String line;
    public void run() {
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    textArea.append(line);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}.start();
```

This code should be run when the button is clicked.

Comment: In my case, Process is not exactly object of Process class. It is just call some functionality. Can you please explain how do I use above spinet?

Comment: The essentials are: You start a thread which checks the progress of the functionality and periodically calls `JTextArea.append`.

Comment: `append()` is not thread safe, if you are working with Java 7. So as pointed by @bellabax, OP must use a SwingWorker (the ONE who deleted his/her answer)

Comment: OP could also use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`, which i will provide an example of in the answer.

Comment: Same goes for me too, till __kleopatra and trashgod__ told me this thingy, quite recently :-)

Comment: @tbodt I got your point. But I don't have any kind of outside process. I am trying to read Images from one folder, doing some functionality and go for next image file. Now I want to show on screen which Image I am reading currently. This everything is running with Java code only. I don't have any process name or external executable file. Please let me know If I am thinking in wrong way

Comment: You can put your image grabbing functionality in a thread, and insert calls to `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` to change the image displayed periodically.